# How do I remove float64 from Pandas query

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on my first student project with the Iris Dataset and learning Pandas. I wondered if anyone can help? I'm trying to remove dtype: float64 from the pandas results. I am also noticing the results are prefixed with 37m on the other part of the print statement.

Reading solutions to similar questions I have tried substituting

**IrisData = pd.read_csv('IRIS.csv')**

with

**IrisData = pd.loadtxt('IRIS.csv', dtype='float')**

but this returns errors

raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'loadtxt'

CODE USED TO GET THE AVERAGE SIZE OF ALL IRIS

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd

# Creating the dataframe 
IrisData = pd.read_csv('IRIS.csv')

# sum over the column axis.
averageofdata = IrisData.mean(axis = 0, skipna = True)

print("Average Sizes of All Iris Data")
print(averageofdata)
```

RESULTS OF CODE

[image]

Comment: Well, the error code says it all, pd.loadtxt doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0):

You should make the difference between a data and the way it is displayed. The `dtype: float64` is displayed because you are printing a pandas `Series`. A simple way to get rid of it is to convert the Series into a DataFrame:

```
print(pd.DataFrame(averageofdata))
```

For the `[37m`, it is probably the ANSI escape sequence `Esc [ 3 7 m`. Those are used on certain terminals for fancy displays (colors, blinkink, etc.). I cannot remember what this one is for, and cannot guess what produced it.

Comment: Thank you Serge, your solution did indeed remove dtype: float64, and your comments about the fancy colours make sense. I imported colorama for fancy text displays, it doesn't work in Idle though, but does on the terminal. I do have another question, I now have a zero as a header on my right column results, it is definitely better than having a  dtype: float64 on the bottom.